# Doxygen and Graphviz on Lion

Tags: path, doxygen, graphviz

I have succesfully installed Doxygen and GraphViz on my mac (running Lion OS), but when I run doxygen with graphViz I get following error messages:

```
1) sh: dot: command not found
2) Problems running dot: exit code=127, command='dot', arguments='"/Users/../xxx.dot" -Tpdf -o
3) error: problems opening map file /Users/.../xxx_graph.map for inclusion in the docs!
If you installed Graphviz/dot after a previous failing run, 
try deleting the output directory and rerun doxygen.
```

It must be a problem with my Graphviz/dot paths, but I dont know how to solve it.

I have already installed Graphviz using MacPorts but I still get the same error messages.

What could I do to solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

Issue this on the command line and see if it solve the problem. You may also need to add it in  `~/.profile`

Refer to [MacPorts' doc](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/InstallingMacPorts#a3.Settheshellenvironment) if you need more information.

Comment: A heads up - if you're using zsh and have your PATH configuration in your .zshrc file the GUI doxygen tool won't pick it up.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks @cyfdecyf and @fkerber for your answers. WIth your answer I could be able to run the dot programm from the console, but I was not able to run doxygen with it. I did not know, but one has to manually give in the path of the dot program in the doxygen user interface. To do this one have to click on `Expert -> dot (under topics menu) ->` and give the path under DOT_PATH, in my case it was `/usr/local/bin`.

Thanks guys.

Comment: You should be accepting this answer for posterity sake. Just upvote the other two answers to acknowledge that those pointers were indeed helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have put the path to your dot executable in your PATH variable so that it can be found if someone is just typing dot in the console.

Perhaps this page can help you:
http://www.sweeting.org/mark/blog/2008/05/26/mac-os-x-tip-setting-path-environment-variables